Arbitrary values not working in Tailwindcss
I'm trying to use arbitrary values in my html program using tailwindcss, however no matter what I try it seem to not work. I also have tried adding them to my tailwind.config.js file and using them as an extension but that seen to not work either. I also have tried removing extend{} and just adding them under theme, but still no results.
Here is the tailwind.config.js file:


/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./venv/templates/**/*.{html,js}"], 
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        'custom-blue': '#1692AC',
        'custom-pink': '#AA1A55',
        'custom-red': '#F7435F',
        'custom-orange': '#F78160',
      },
      minHeight: {
        '95': '23.3rem', // 372.8px
      },
      height:{
        '500' : '500px'
      }
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}



A HTML code snippet: (the custom blue also does not apply)
  <div class="flex px-20 mt-16">
    <div class="bg-gray-300 flex-auto hover:bg-custom-blue w-[100px] h-[200px]">
      <h2 class="font-bold top-0 left-0 p-1" style="font-size: xx-large; color: #1692AC">Something</h2>
    </div>
  </div>


Please share the html code with the tailwind classes that are not working. There's no way we can guess why your code is not working from the currently available information. Please see how to write a [mre].

there is some missing part of your project. first try to make your project correctly. use this to initialize npm in your project. npm init -y Install Tailwind CSS and its dependencies. npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer Generate the tailwind.config.js and postcss.config.js files. npx tailwindcss init -p now create style.css file and insert this inside of file.
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

now use this to build your css file npx tailwindcss build main.css -o output.css now link your build css file to html file.
<link href="./output.css" rel="stylesheet">

your tailwind.config.js and project structure need to be like this. after doing any style change build your css file.


do i need to keep npx tailwindcss -i ./main.css -o ./output.css --watch running at all times for the changes to work? sorry I know these questions are basic. Kind of new to tailwindcss

yes, please refer to https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation for more...
